# Execute a function inside script tag

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'calendars','method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'eventform')) !!}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th >{!! Form::label('titles', 'Title') !!}</th>

        <td >{!! Form::text('title') !!}<br><br></td>
    </tr>

            @if($errors->has('title'))
                <tr><td></td>
                <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$errors->first('title')}}</ul></td>
                </tr>
            @endif



    <tr>
    <tr>

        <td> <b>{!! Form::label('Types', 'Type') !!}</b></td>

        <td>


            {!! Form::select('type', array('type' => 'type','Orange' => 'Orange', 'Red' => 'Red','Green' => 'Green'), 'type', ['id' => 'type']) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('color','', ['id' => 'color']) !!}
        </td>

    </tr>

        <th >{!! Form::label('dates', 'Event Date') !!}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <td >{!! Form::input('date', 'eventDate', $value = null, $options = array()) !!}<br><br></td>
     </tr>
            @if($errors->has('eventDate'))
        <tr><td></td>
            <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$errors->first('eventDate')}}</ul></td>
        </tr>


            @endif
    <tr>
        <th >{!! Form::label('Venue', 'Venue') !!}</th>
        <td >{!! Form::text('venue') !!}<br><br></td>

    </tr>
    @if($errors->has('venue'))
        <tr><td></td>
            <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$errors->first('venue')}}</ul></td>
        </tr>


    @endif
    <tr>
        <th >{!! Form::label('Time', 'Time') !!}</th>
        <td >{!! Form::input('time', 'time', $value = null, $options = array()) !!}<br><br></td>
    </tr>
    @if($errors->has('time'))
        <tr><td></td>
            <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$errors->first('time')}}</ul></td>
        </tr>


    @endif
    @if(Session::has('error1'))
        <tr><td></td>
        <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px">{!! Session::get('error1') !!}</ul></td>
        </tr>
    @endif

    <tr>
    <td colspan='2' align='center'>{!! Form::submit('Add', array('class'=>'Add')) !!} </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


        {!! Form::close() !!}

        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#type').on('change', function(){
                    $('#color').val($('#type').val());
                });
            });
        </script>
```

How should I execute this script code? Where should I call? That is in the view blade.php file. Form is also there. Do I need to call that on submit button? The above code is to change a hidden input value according to selected drop box value

Comment: are you getting error in console?

Comment: no. Only problem I guess script was not executed. Because hidden input value not set by the selected drop box value

Comment: Can you add the related markups?

Comment: <select id="type" name="type"><option value="type" selected="selected">type</option><option value="Orange">Orange</option><option value="Red">Red</option><option value="Green">Green</option></select>

Comment: <input id="color" name="color" type="hidden" value="">
<input class="Add" type="submit" value="Add">                                 <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/calendars" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="eventform"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="vr7XpEeRlIVbBbAh15dNcEjJzIMLCJhB4nXP57I0">

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't post code in the comments

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pjjzt1on/ your code works ok

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run it manually. As long as it has been loaded, it will work when you change the drop box with id **type**.

Try this (instead of document.ready...):

```
....
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#type').on('change', function(){
               $('#color').val($('#type').val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Edit**
Here is the sample code (complete html and it works). After playing with the select, press the Button to display the value of the hidden input. Copy and save it to a html file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#type').on('change', function(){
               $('#color').val($('#type').val());
            });
        });
    </script>
    <select id='type'>
        <option>Value1</option>
        <option>Value2</option>
        <option>Value3</option>
    </select>
    <input name='foo' type='hidden' id='color' value='Value1'/>

    <button onclick='alert($("#color").val())'>Show Hidden Value</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are not receiving it from the server side, then you should check your hidden input name.

**Edit**

I copied your code, and created a laravel project here

https://laravello-yerlibilgin.c9users.io/YourProjectName/server.php

, also added a javascript alert. Whenever the value changes, you can see that the hidden value is being successfully set. After changing it  click the **Add** button to see the effect.

The server side handler is like this:

```
 Route::post('/calendars', function () {
     $val =  Input::get('color');
     return $val;
 });
```

This code works successfully and receives the value of the hidden input. Please check your server side as well.

Comment: No. Still hidden field get empty

Comment: Please consider the above sample code that I added. If it doesn't work, then please edit your post and add your full code so that we can check what is the problem

Comment: I want to save the hidden field value and post to controller

Comment: Please post your full code in your original message. Obviously there is no problem with the script. You have a problem either on the server side or in the other parts of the code. The above code works.

Comment: Please check the additional explanation and confirm if it works. Of course I expect a +1 and an accepted answer :)